# HTML5 Boilerplate ignoring folders via file.exclude

Tags: ant, build, html5boilerplate

Hi guys I've just got my build script set up with HTML5 Boilerplate.

There are several files / folders in the root of my site that I don't want to be copied over to the publish folder. I have set file.exclude in project.properties as follows:

file.exclude      = .settings, .buildpath, .project, tests, php_errors.log

This is working for the files in the list (.buildpath, .project, php_errors.log), but not the folders (.settings and tests).

Can someone tell me how to prevent these folders getting copied over to my publish folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, to ignore the **scss** and **.sass-cache** folders on build:

`file.exclude = **/.sass-cache/**, **/scss/**`

H5BP ignores a couple of folders by default, such as .git and .svn, and you can see how they do it here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/build/config/default.properties